# ColdFusion 10 getting element is undefined in form error

Tags: coldfusion, multi-select, coldfusion-10, cfml

I've got a ColdFusion 10 form, to which I'm adding a new multiple select list

```
<SELECT multiple="multiple" id="icd9list" 
    name="icd9list" 
    size="2" 
    class="pageText2" 
    style="width:400px;">
</SELECT>
```

It shows up on the form correctly and I can get items added to it with JavaScript, but when I go to process the form, the form action page is giving the following error:

> Element ICD9LIST is undefined in FORM.

I've added cfparam tags on the initial form page, as well as the form action page where I'm getting the error.

Can't for the life of me figure out why it's not passing the form element to the action page. The method is `post`, so it should be picking it up. All of the other form elements on the page are picked up fine.

```
<cfform action="updform.cfm" name="custform" method="POST">
```

I also tried to use `custform.icd9list` and got the same issue:

> Element ICD9LIST is undefined in CUSTFORM.

This page is some VERY legacy code that we can't really go back and refactor too much. The only thing I'm thinking is that when the page first loads, the multiple select option is blank and then we are adding options to it via javascript from a pop-out window after the fact. When I inspect the element in Chrome, after I've added options to it, they are there, but I'm wondering if it's still being treated as a blank multiple select list. I do know that if I remove the multiple attribute and treat the form element as a single drop down list that it shows up in the form dump with a value, but only the first (or whatever selected) value.

Beginning to think the answer may be to have a hidden field with the option values populated and let the form read that.

Comment: Are you actually selecting something? Adding items to a multiple select doesnt mean anything, you still need to actually select the items. In the past I have done this on submit, just select all the items that have been added.

Comment: @haxtbh Even if you don't select anything, won't the SELECT form element still be there anyway?

Comment: Are you using any other JS library on this page? What happens if you remove the attribute value from multiple and just type `multiple`?

Comment: @Shawn  No, a bit like check boxes, radio buttons or any disabled form item. If they are not ticked / active etc they don't get passed in the form scope .

Comment: Hmmm... I know a SELECT has to have an OPTION, but I thought it would still pass through the form, even if an OPTION wasn't selected. I guess add that to the list of things I didn't realize I'd forgotten or just never really tested. :-)

Comment: *"Tried to use custform.icd9list"*  FWIW, you never use the name of the `cfform`. In CF, POST variables are always submitted to a special system scope named `FORM` (regardless of the name of the cfform/form).

Comment: @haxtbh - Sorry, didn't notice you'd already suggested [selecting the items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52048717/8895292). If you want to post that as an answer, I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 4):

Adding options to a multiple select list isn't enough. They have to be selected as well. Otherwise, the list isn't considered a [successful control](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls) and the field *won't* be passed to the action page (emphasis mine)

> A successful control is "valid" for submission. Every successful
>   control has its control name paired with its current value as part of
>   the submitted form data set. A successful control must be defined
>   within a FORM element and must have a control name.
>
> However:
>
> - Controls that are disabled cannot be successful.
> - If a form contains more than one submit button, only the activated submit button is successful.
> - All "on" checkboxes may be successful.
> - For radio buttons that share the same value of the name attribute, only the "on" radio button may be successful.
> - For menus, the control name is provided by a SELECT element and values are provided by OPTION elements. Only selected options may be
>     successful. **When no options are selected, the control is not
>     successful and neither the name nor any values are submitted to the
>     server when the form is submitted**.
> - The current value of a file select is a list of one or more file names. Upon submission of the form, the contents of each file are
>     submitted with the rest of the form data. The file contents are
>     packaged according to the form's content type.
> - The current value of an object control is determined by the object's implementation.

I suspect the form isn't forcing the items to be "selected" before the form is submitted and that's why nothing shows up on the action page.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need one of two things

Either required it on the client side

```
<SELECT multiple="multiple" required id="icd9list" name="icd9list" size="2" class="pageText2" style="width:400px;">
...
</SELECT>
```

Or make sure ColdFusion can handle it not existing on the server side.

```
<cfparam name="icd9list" default="">
```

As pointed out,

```
<cfparam name="form.icd9list" default="">
```

will get an even tighter scope

Comment: Even better, use both ;-) @jjasper0729 - Also be sure to include the scope in the cfparam, ie `<cfparam name="form.icd9list` default="">`.

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling on the form? Are you using `form.variable` or `icd9list.variable`? You shouldn't have to give it an ID or name unless there are multiple forms on the page. You can just `name` and `ID` your element and reference it like this: `form.name`

Comment: I'm referencing it as form.icd9list in updform.cfm (the form action file)

Comment: Thats not how you access a form variable. you are basically saying form.form since you named your form icd9list. Take away the name and ID off your form. Then name and ID the inputs as desired. Example: <form method="post"> <input name="name" id="name" type="text"></form> You would want to reference this as form.name

Comment: And also you want your cfparam to be name="form.name" and each time you call on it, needs to be specified as form.name unless you cfset form.name as a new variable name.

Comment: no.. the form is actually named "custform" (see the cfform tag in the initial post). I'll try to see if custform.icd9list will work. icd9list is the form element name

Comment: Try custform.icd9list, but if it doesn't work I would like to take a look at your code so I can more easily tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Also, I wanted to add that I generally avoid using cfform. You can pass values from one page to another using POST with regular HTML form tags

Comment: had too much to write than would fit in the comments so I edited the question @needingSomeAnswers